# Not able to receive data from Wemo device with UPNP request swift

Tags: ios, swift, upnp, gcdasyncudpsocket

I have Wemo belkin device in my local network i'm sending data with upnp call but i'm not able to receive reponse from wemo device.
Here is my code :

```
class PluginBelkinViewController: UIViewController, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate {
    let ssdpAddres = "239.255.255.250"
    let ssdpPort:UInt16 = 1900
    var ssdpSocket:GCDAsyncUdpSocket!
    var ssdpSocketRec:GCDAsyncUdpSocket!
    var error: NSError?

    @IBAction func nextPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let mSearchData = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: \(ssdpAddres):\(ssdpPort)\r\nMAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\nMX: 5\r\nST: urn:Belkin:device\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        do {
            ssdpSocket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
            ssdpSocket.sendData(mSearchData, toHost: ssdpAddres, port: ssdpPort, withTimeout: 5000, tag: 0)
            try ssdpSocket.bindToPort(ssdpPort)
            try ssdpSocket.joinMulticastGroup(ssdpAddres)
            try ssdpSocket.beginReceiving()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        let otherSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

        do {
            try otherSocket.acceptOnPort(8901)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromAddress address: NSData, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject?) {
        print("--------- didReceiveData ----------")
        let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        print(str)
    }

    func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:Int)
    {
        print("--------- didReceiveResponse ----------")
        let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        print(str)
    }
}
```

And here is the response i'm getting :

> --------- didReceiveData ----------
>
> M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
>
> HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
>
> MAN: "ssdp:discover"
>
> MX: 1
>
> ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1
>
> USER-AGENT: Google Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Mac OS X
>
> --------- didReceiveData ----------
>
> M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
>
> HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
>
> MAN: "ssdp:discover"
>
> MX: 1
>
> ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1
>
> USER-AGENT: Google Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Mac OS X

**Solved :**

I fixed the problem, here is my full code i did, if someone have the same issue :

```
class PluginBelkinViewController: UIViewController, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate {

    var address = "239.255.255.250"
    var port:UInt16 = 1900
    var socket:GCDAsyncUdpSocket!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func nextPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let mSearchData = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: \(address):\(port)\r\nMAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\nMX: 5\r\nST: urn:Belkin:device:\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        socket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

        do {
            try socket.bindToPort(0)
            try socket.beginReceiving()
            try socket.enableBroadcast(true)
        } catch {
            socket.close()
            print(error)
        }

        socket.sendData(mSearchData, toHost: address, port: port, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)

        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.stopDiscover()
        }
    }

    func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromAddress address: NSData, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject?) {
        var host: NSString?
        var port1: UInt16 = 0
        GCDAsyncUdpSocket.getHost(&host, port: &port1, fromAddress: address)
        let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        print(str)
    }

    func stopDiscover(){
        socket.close()
        socket = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: copying and pasting error logs is preferred over screenshots

Comment: I fixed the problem, above post updated with the solution